# Ant compiles classes no matter what

Tags: java, ant

I'm using ant 1.10.0 on a windows 7 box.

I'm having a very weird problem with ant.
I first run ant to delete existing .class files which works perfectly.
I then run ant to compile my java source code and re-generate the .class files.

Here's what's happening:
1. the timestamp on the classes is from two days ago.
2. I have verified that my computer has the correct date/time though.
3. If I run ant clean, and then ant compile, ant will compile 164 classes.
4. If I immediately run ant compile a second time, ant should not compile any source code because I just built the class files and they are up to date.
5. But instead of doing nothing, ant re-compiles 83 source files.
   I have no idea why this is happening.

Anyone ever run into this?

Comment: Note that if you use ant -debug, it will display the reason why it compiled a given file.

Comment: Thanks very much for that useful tip.  I tracked down the problem, and of course it was me.  I had a folder with some old .class files in it that I needed to delete.  Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down the problem, and of course it was me. I had a folder with some old .class files in it that I needed to delete.